# How to filter out array elements where object may or may not exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider a JavaScript array like this:

```
  var testArray=
    [
    {name:'test1', source: {type:'1' },
    {name:'test2',
    {name:'test3', source: {type:'1' }
    {name:'test4',
    {name:'test5', source:{type:'2'},
    {name:'test5', source:{type:'3'},
    ]
```

I want to filter this array and return all elements except where `type===1`. However as you can see, some of the elements don't have the source object.

If I do this:

```
const filteredData = testArray.filter(itm=>itm.source && itm.source.type !=='1')
```

It removes elements that don't have a source attribute.

How can I filter this array to retrieve all items except for where there is a source.type !== 1 ?

Comment: If you want to have those that are not 1, then that is `!itm.source || itm.source.type !== '1'`

Comment: `testArray` is not valid JS, so maybe start there?

Comment: Syntax Error on the Array Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition to

```
!itm.source || itm.source.type !== '1'
```

This will not filter out any items that don't have the source first. All that remain have source so you are safe to check if it is '1'.

Comment: You don't need the `&&` on the right hand side.  The only way the right hand side will evaluate is if there is a source, due to the left hand side being false.

Comment: This isn't solving the problem though, it is filtering out items that don't have a source. you have to filter out items where `item.source.type !== "1"`

Comment: @shadowtime2000 No, if source is not defined then `!itm.source` is true.  and <some array>.filter(it => true)` returns the elements

Comment: What @Taplar is trying to say is `if(!itm.source || itm.source.type !== '1')` should work, I think.

Comment: Right, because for elements to be returned from a filter, the expression has to return `true`.  `!itm.source` is true if there is no source property

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It will cause the expression to evaluate to `undefined` when trying to access properties on `null` or `undefined`.

```js
  var testArray=
    [
    {name:'test1', source: {type:'1' }},
    {name:'test2'},
    {name:'test3', source: {type:'1' }},
    {name:'test4'},
    {name:'test5', source:{type:'2'}},
    {name:'test5', source:{type:'3'}},
    ]
const filteredData = testArray.filter(itm=>itm.source?.type !=='1');
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
testArray.filter(i => i.source?.type !== "1")
```

Will use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to determine if `i.source` exists and then checks if it is equal to `"1"`, if it is don't keep it. If not keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note that your array is wrong, some of the objects are not closed "}")

```
 var testArray=[
    {name:'test1', source: {type:'1' }},
    {name:'test2'},
    {name:'test3', source: {type:'1' }},
    {name:'test4'},
    {name:'test5', source:{type:'2'}},
    {name:'test5', source:{type:'3'}},
    ];

const filteredData = testArray.filter(itm=>!itm.source || itm.source.type !=='1')
```